# Issue with Python list interaction with for loop

Tags: python, list, append

I am having a problem with my genetic feature optimization algorithm that I am attempting to build. The idea is that a specific combination of features will be tested and if the model accuracy using those features is higher than the previous maximum, then the combination of features replaces the previous maximum combination. through running through the remaining potential features in this way, the final combination should be the optimal combination of features given the feature vector size. Currently, the code that looks to achieve this looks like:

```
def mutate_features(features, feature):
    new_features = features
    index = random.randint(0,len(features)-1)
    new_features[index] = feature
    return new_features

def run_series(n, f_list, df):
    features_list = []
    results_list = []
    max_results_list = [[0,0,0,0,0]]
    max_feature_list = []
    features = [0,0,0,0,1]
    for i in range(0,5):  # 5 has just been chosen as the range for testing purposes
        results = run_algorithm(df, f_list, features)
        features_list.append(features)
        results_list.append(results)
        if (check_result_vector(max_results_list, results)):
            max_results_list.append(results)
            max_feature_list.append(features)
        else:
            print("Revert to previous :" +str(max_feature_list[-1]))
            features = max_feature_list[-1]
        features = mutate_features(features, f_list[i])
        print("Feature List = " +str(features_list))
        print("Results List = " +str(results_list))
        print("Max Results List = " +str(max_results_list))
        print("Max Feature List = "+str(max_feature_list))
```

The output from this code has been included below;

[image: Output]
<sup>*Click to zoom or enlarge the photo*</sup>

The section that I do not understand is the output of the `max_feature_list` and `feature_list`.

If anything is added through the use of `.append()` to the `max_feature_list` or the `feature_list` inside the for loop, it seems to change all items that are already members of the list to be the same as the latest addition to the list. I may not be fully understanding of the syntax/logic around this and would really appreciate any feedback as to why the program is doing this.

Comment: You sure you don't modify `max_feature_list` inside your (not shown) `mutate_features` function?

Comment: I don't believe it is modified, I will edit the original post to show the mutate features function.

Comment: Easiest way to debug this is to include a temporary `print(max_feature_list)` statement just after `max_feature_list.append(features)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you change the values of `features` inside `mutate_features` function and then, since the append to `max_feature_list` is by reference, the populated values in `max_feature_list` are changing too because their underlying value changed.

One way to prevent such behaviour is to `deepcopy` `features` inside `mutate_features`, mutate the copied features as you want and then return it.

For example:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def mutate_features(features, feature):
    new_features = deepcopy(features)
    index = random.randint(0,len(features)-1)
    new_features[index] = feature
    return new_features


features = [1, 2, 3]
res = []
res.append(features)
features = mutate_features(features, feature)
res.append(features)
print(res)
```

Comment: `features` is not changed inside `mutate_features`; this was my first thought, too, but after OP posting the code this is evidently not the case.

Comment: `new_features` and `features` are 2 references to the same value (the assignment of `features` to `new_features` is by ref and not by value) so in that case, changing `new_features` is the same as changing `features`.

Comment: This simple change fixed the issue! I was not aware that append() to max_feature_list is by reference, thank you for your help.

Comment: @AdamWhitrow happy to help :)